# Implement A2DP sink on linux system using dbus-python api

Tags: python, linux, bluetooth, dbus, a2dp

I want to implement a custom A2DP sink on my linux system running the latest Ubuntu 12.04 with the latest bluez stack.

My Basic Requirements are:

- Linux system to act as a receiver(like a bluetooth headset with automatic authentication with default key "0000" or "anything")
- I want to use dbus-python API to communicate with bluez stack. I want to run my own algorithm to configure communication parameters in runtime, thats y i want to implement my own sink.
- later i also want to implement HSP and HFP profiles for my linux system.

Basically, I want to run these profiles and test the external bluetooth module which is connected via usb with my linux system for various audio transmission configurations and evaluate the performance under different profiles for audio reception.

I know there must be open source code already available in the web. But i couldn't find one. Even if the code is written in C or JAVA it doesn't matter for me. I require it for my educational purpose and I cannot buy commercial codes. So, people with expertise kindly help me out in creating this test bed. Because, my main objective is to modify bluez stack in future and I dont want to waste time in creating the test bed.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Ubuntu supports A2DP sink out of the box, and all of the code is open source.  Which exact part of the stack are you trying to customize?

Comment: I want to import the source code for A2DP sink in eclipse and run it and debug it. change the transmission parameters ex: change the sampling rate from 44.1khz to 16khz, etc... I want to customize l2cap, avdtp layers.